# FAISS: how to get euclidean distance between the vectors

Tags: python, euclidean-distance, faiss

I have a set of the vectors for index training

```
train = [[0.8037452  0.29432032 0.7007814  0.87885666 0.7204465  0.90595365
0.553066   0.91305405 0.7757398  0.60006464]
 [0.68810666 0.6761919  0.0508003  0.9548363  0.3328804  0.5403833
0.28921887 0.8051086  0.3456949  0.42990723]
 [0.54076064 0.3242226  0.06708261 0.87584656 0.0951417  0.7335189
0.4225589  0.8217667  0.37197167 0.7536059 ]
 [0.23287264 0.41105017 0.6217458  0.41283417 0.38538024 0.76463556
0.3311062  0.9342876  0.31805852 0.92445046]
 [0.69405013 0.31568167 0.7361599  0.67789274 0.13494864 0.08621287
0.97758645 0.3436561  0.49988484 0.97549576]
 [0.25660193 0.5157562  0.8962387  0.33710077 0.57156765 0.15350631
0.856847   0.47084704 0.53191525 0.27804178]
 [0.42284343 0.4465723  0.11332349 0.5902145  0.18484402 0.66718507
0.6943475  0.74991924 0.644108   0.29665214]
 [0.21185638 0.6709447  0.35902056 0.09483628 0.99569106 0.855805
0.07330076 0.8412446  0.6725694  0.27089283]
 [0.06507999 0.49600333 0.6139055  0.60085547 0.3116162  0.24808735
0.24514997 0.45627877 0.1732836  0.83035445]
 [0.2699826  0.7498663  0.45234948 0.00871892 0.63637036 0.52080977
0.59493476 0.8574138  0.59167767 0.35376287]]
```

And I try to get the nearest neighbors for the vectors

```
test = [[0.06507999 0.49600333 0.6139055  0.60085547 0.3116162  0.24808735
0.24514997 0.45627877 0.1732836  0.83035445]
 [0.2699826  0.7498663  0.45234948 0.00871892 0.63637036 0.52080977
0.59493476 0.8574138  0.59167767 0.40376288]]
```

When I use `spacy.spatial.distance. euclidean` I get correct distances

```
for i, x in enumerate(test):
    for j, y in enumerate(train):
        euc_dist = euclidean(x, y)
        print(f"Euclidean dist for {i} and {j} vecs: {euc_dist}")

Euclidean dist for 0 and 0 vecs: 1.4108535051345825
Euclidean dist for 0 and 1 vecs: 1.1236623525619507
Euclidean dist for 0 and 2 vecs: 1.0598790645599365
Euclidean dist for 0 and 3 vecs: 0.7802197337150574
Euclidean dist for 0 and 4 vecs: 1.087794303894043
Euclidean dist for 0 and 5 vecs: 1.034853219985962
Euclidean dist for 0 and 6 vecs: 1.1693437099456787
Euclidean dist for 0 and 7 vecs: 1.396589756011963
Euclidean dist for 0 and 8 vecs: 0.0
Euclidean dist for 0 and 9 vecs: 1.1612287759780884
Euclidean dist for 1 and 0 vecs: 1.2425576448440552
Euclidean dist for 1 and 1 vecs: 1.2192267179489136
Euclidean dist for 1 and 2 vecs: 1.301788330078125
Euclidean dist for 1 and 3 vecs: 0.9231050610542297
Euclidean dist for 1 and 4 vecs: 1.443143606185913
Euclidean dist for 1 and 5 vecs: 0.8581254482269287
Euclidean dist for 1 and 6 vecs: 0.9107089638710022
Euclidean dist for 1 and 7 vecs: 0.7507518529891968
Euclidean dist for 1 and 8 vecs: 1.1416186094284058
Euclidean dist for 1 and 9 vecs: 0.050000011920928955
```

However, when I try to use `faiss` `IndexFlatL2` to store it, it returns me another values of euclidean distances.

```
index = faiss.IndexFlatL2(10)
index.add(train)
dist, ind = index.search(test, 3)

dist - [[0.        0.6087429 1.0709212]
        [0.0025    0.5636283 0.7363793]] 
indices - [[8 3 5]
           [9 7 5]]
```

For example, we see that for the 1-st vector from the test set the Euclidean dist between 9-th vector from the train is 0.050000011920928955.
But `faiss` returns 0.0025.

How can I get real values of the distances using faiss?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is as simple as it gets : `faiss` distances are returned **squared** while `euclidean` returns the the **squared root**.

So 1st vector vs 9th is 0.05^2 == 0.0025, all fine.

`faiss`:
https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss/wiki/MetricType-and-distances#metric_l2

`euclidean`: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean.html